# Polymer, JavaScript, PHP: Get data from PHP as Variable

Tags: javascript, php, polymer

I'm trying to make a PWA that displays some data from a PHP file that makes a request and grabs data (weather) from another website.

After research I found out that I cannot use JavaScript to "crawl" external websites. I have made an PHP script that crawls the specified website and grabs the data I need.

a.php:

```
<?php
$currweather = 'http://weatherweb.com/Dublin';
$contentweather = file_get_contents($currweather);
$wth = explode( '<div id="weather">' , $contentweather );
$wthg = explode("</div>" , $wth[1] );

echo wthg[0];
?>
```

This file outputs the exact data as: "28 Celsius".

This is my Polymer file:

```
<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2016 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-image/iron-image.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">


<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-view1">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;

        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="card">
<iron-ajax
  auto
  url="src/a.php"
  handle-as="text"
  last-response="{{handleResponse}}"></iron-ajax>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{handleResponse}}">

  </template>


    <div class="weath" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
      <center>
      <div class="weathc" style="flex: 1;">
      <img width="80%" height="auto" src="../images/sun.png">
      </div>
      <div class="curr_weather" style="flex:1">Feels like:
      </div>
    </center>
      </div>



    </div>
      </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    class MyView1 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-view1'; }


    }


    window.customElements.define(MyView1.is, MyView1);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

If I use the iron-ajax code that already is in the script, my console gives this error:

```
dom-repeat.html:445 dom-repeat expected array for `items`, found <?php
$currweather = 'http://weatherweb.com/Dublin';
$contentweather = file_get_contents($currweather);
$wth = explode( '<div id="weather">' , $contentweather );
$wthg = explode("</div>" , $wth[1] );

echo wthg[0];
?>
```

How can I make Polymer and Javascript crawl this file (that I can store locally), and store the php echo as variable?
Thank you!

Comment: It seems , there is  typo in the last line of your code ,`echo wthg[0]; ` must be `echo $wthg[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Your app is considering php as a static file where it should be actually a script. Use

```
- url: /src/a.php
  script: src/a.php
```

in your app.yaml file.